# Rings are isomorphic iff prime spectrums are homeomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A, B$ be two commutative rings with identities. It is trivial to show that $A \cong B \implies \operatorname{Spec}{A} = \operatorname{Spec}{B}$. Is the converse true? If not, what is a counterexample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No; take any two non-isomorphic fields, they will only have one prime ideal, thus resulting in the same topology.